# Big O Notation Of Exponential Functions

Tags: algorithm

I have noticed that big-O of 1000n or 10n is the same thing as O(n), but big-O of 2^n and 3^n are different: O(2^n) and O(3^n), what I don't get is why can't we ignore the constants in this case (2 or 3) and whether there is any mathematical proof  justifying this?

Comment: You don't ignore constants in big-O notation. You ignore coefficients. 2 and 3 are bases, not coefficients.

Comment: Can you state the definition of Big-Oh? Remember that Big-Oh has a mathematical definition and shouldn't be used entirely intuitively. Memorizing that "you can ignore constants sometimes" is a bad habit, in my opinion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because there is no constant value of `k` that satisfies the inequality `3^n <= k * 2^n` for arbitrarily large `n`.  Thus `f(n) = 3^n` is not a member of `O(2^n)`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations.

Comment: To be precise, you are exhibiting a counterexample to the claim that `O(3^n) = O(2^n)`. In particular, `f(n) = 3^n` is in `O(3^n)` but not in `O(2^n)` using the argument you gave above. Therefore the sets are not equal via the Axiom of Extensionality

Comment: @roliu: I don't know what that axiom is, but yes, that's the implied argument ;)

Comment: It's an axiom in the most popular set theory, ZFC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory. It just says "two sets are equal iff they contain the same elements". No one ever cites it in a real proof, but I'm just trying to convince SO to start using actual mathematical reasoning instead of intuition (by being extremely verbose with math jargon). If you are just trying to decide which implementation to use while you're writing code you can use intuition. When someone says "prove this" then I think you should, you know, use math :)

Comment: @roliu: Hmm, I think most people here would be satisfied with "two sets aren't equal if they don't have the same members" without having to resort to a proof/jargon!  Set theory axioms are probably a little out of scope for SO (as opposed to CS/Math StackExchange).  But thanks for the link, I'm always interested to learn a bit of interesting maths...

Comment: Yeah. Most people on S.O. couldn't prove their way out of a paper bag. (Myself, included.) Waaaaaay, way over-the-head and out-of-scope, here. >:

Comment: (and … seven months later, I arrive at this same question via a different route, looking specifically for the information @rliu provided. Guess it just goes to show.)

Answer (score 4):

Eventhough for the original asker this might not be of use anymore, 
I think it can be approached in an easier way.

*Basic defenition of O-notation: iff f(g) would be in O(g(n)),
 
then there exist a rational number c, for which it holds that f(g) = c * g(n), for n >= n0 
(n0 being a number that you pick yourself)*

Let's try to apply this for 3^n in O(2^n)
*3^n = 2^n * c* 
*3^n = 2^n * (3^n / 2^n)*
*3^n = 2^n * (3/2)^n*
*3^n = 2^n * 1.5^n*

this means that c = 1.5^n which is not a rational number, but an exponential function on its own.

On the other hand, following the same for 3^n in O(2^n), we would get 2^n <= 3^n * (2/3)^n

This might seem like a conflict, until you realise that 0.75^n < 1 for all n > 0, which means that if you take any c > 1, it will be larger than 0.67^n from n = 0

Answer (score 1):

to campare two complexities, f(n) and g(n) you applied the limit:
lim_{n->\inf} f(n)/g(n) and you have three posible answers:

1) lim_{n->\inf} f(n)/g(n) = 0;
   this imply that f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) and g(n) ∉ O(f(n))

2) lim_{n->\inf} f(n)/g(n) = +/- inf;
   this imply that f(n) ∉ O(g(n)) and g(n) ∈ O(f(n))

3) lim_{n->\inf} f(n)/g(n) ∈ Real number;
   this imply that f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) and g(n) ∈ O(f(n))

Then to demostrade 2^n ∈ O(3^n) you operate like this

lim_{n->\inf} 2^n/3^n = lim_{n->\inf} (2/3)^n = 0

And is demostrated, and we also demostraded 3^n ∉ O(2^n), and is easy to see that 2/3 < 1 this make the limit to converge to 0 then the result of the limit depends of the constants, I mean lim_{n->inf} a^n = 0 if 0 < a < 1 and lim_{n->inf} a^n = inf if a > 1;

For a better understanding check: Introduction to Algorithms, Third Edition
By Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein

I'm professor of algorithms, I hope it helped you. Take care.